# onPrepareOptionMenu menu?.findItem returns null android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, toolbar, menuitem, android-appbarlayout

I want to add a custom view to my MainActivity Toolbar.
So i create the layout.xml file with the view inside and i add it to the main_menu.xml but i can never take it from the onPrepareOptionsMenu on my Activity.

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/contact_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/currentServerViewItem"
        android:title="My account"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/main_toolbar_views"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_aboutus"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="About us"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

main_toolbar_views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentServerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="UU"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
 private var currentServerTextView: TextView? = null 

 ....

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.contact_search)?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                newText?.let {
                    mainViewModel.setSearchable(it)
                }
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

.....

 override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
   // Here i get a nullPointer exception
        val menuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.currentServerViewItem)?.actionView as ConstraintLayout
        currentServerTextView = menuItem.findViewById(R.id.currentServerTextView) as TextView
        currentServerTextView?.setOnClickListener {
            toast("Text Clicked!!!")
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
 }
```

When trying to debug the menuItem i get a nullPointerException although the menu is not null.
Also in the toolbar instead of the TextView layout (which is a circle textView) i see the MyAccount title only.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed. The problem was that i had to set the xml

app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:orderInCategory="100"